# How to navigate to the sidemenu options in ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I am new to ionic. I am trying to access the side menu options by clicking that options. But i am not able to navigate to that page and i'm getting

> "Cannot read property 'component' of undefined"

this error. How can i access those pages by clicking sode menu options.If i use push then all of the options are going to single page not to that spesific page.

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Nav} from 'ionic-angular';
import { DashboardPage } from '../dashboard/dashboard';
import { ProfilePage } from '../profile/profile';
import { sidemenuDeclaration } from '../../sideMenuDeclare';
import { MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FeaturesPage } from '../features/features';
import { MediaPage } from '../media/media';
import { BlogPage } from '../blog/blog';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-menu',
  templateUrl: 'menu.html',
})
export class MenuPage {
@ViewChild(Nav) nav:Nav;

  rootPage:any = DashboardPage;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public menuCtrl: MenuController) {
  }

options : sidemenuDeclaration[] = [
  {title : "Home" , icon : "home" ,component : DashboardPage},
  {title : "Features" ,icon : "settings" , component : FeaturesPage},
  {title : "Media" , icon : "images" , component : MediaPage},
  {title : "Blog" ,icon : "create" ,component : BlogPage},
  {title : "Contact" , icon : "contact" ,component : ProfilePage},
  {title : "Like Us" , icon : "logo-facebook" ,component : ProfilePage},
  {title : "Follow Us" , icon : "logo-twitter" ,component : ProfilePage}
]

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad MenuPage');
  }
  goToProfile(){
    this.navCtrl.push(ProfilePage);
  }

  menuOptions(op){
    this.nav.setRoot(op.component);
  }

}
```

```html
<ion-menu [content]='content'>
    <ion-header>

        <ion-toolbar color = "danger">
            <ion-title (click) = "goToProfile()">
                <ion-icon name="contact"></ion-icon>Profile
            </ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>


    <ion-content padding>
        <button ion-item *ngFor = "let op of options" (click) = "menuOptions()">
            <ion-icon name = {{op.icon}}></ion-icon>
            {{op.title}}
        </button>
    </ion-content>

</ion-menu>

<ion-nav #content [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

Comment: you should pass ```op``` in ```(click) = "menuOptions()"``` to access this in your component.

Comment: You didn't pass an argument when you called the function. Of course it's undefined what else could it be?

Comment: You have not passed op in click option HTML. Replace (click)="menuOptions()"  as menuOptions(op) in html.

Comment: Thank you guys issue solved.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `menuOptions` requires an argument which is not passed in the (html) template. 
Use the following snippet.

```
   <ion-content padding>
        <button ion-item *ngFor = "let op of options" (click) = "menuOptions(op)">
            <ion-icon name = {{op.icon}}></ion-icon>
            {{op.title}}
        </button>
    </ion-content>
```